# Shared Preferences value is not persistent Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Shared Preferences data is getting wiped whenever I close the app. I saw many problems similar to this in stack overflow but none of the solutions helped me. I am stuck with this problem for 1 week now. Finally decided to ask here. Please help! I am trying to save pain scores locally and it works completely fine until I close the app and reopen again. When I reopen the app, for some reason, the shared preferences value is getting wiped. I just cant understand what is happening. I tried running flutter clean and it didn't work as well.

num_pad.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


DateTime scheduleTime = DateTime.now();


// KeyPad widget
// This widget is reusable and its buttons are customizable (color, size)
class NumPad extends StatelessWidget {
  final double buttonSize;
  final Color buttonColor;
  final Color iconColor;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Function delete;
  final Function onSubmit;

  const NumPad(
      {Key? key,
      this.buttonSize = 75,
      this.buttonColor = Colors.blue,
      this.iconColor = Colors.blue,
      required this.controller,
      required this.delete,
      required this.onSubmit})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            // implement the number keys (from 0 to 9) with the NumberButton widget
            // the NumberButton widget is defined in the bottom of this file
            children: [
              NumberButton(
                number: 1,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              NumberButton(
                number: 2,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              NumberButton(
                number: 3,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              NumberButton(
                number: 4,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              NumberButton(
                number: 5,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              NumberButton(
                number: 6,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              NumberButton(
                number: 7,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              NumberButton(
                number: 8,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              NumberButton(
                number: 9,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              NumberButton(
                number: 10,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              // this button is used to delete the last number
              NumberButton(
                number: 0,
                size: buttonSize,
                color: buttonColor,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              // this button is used to submit the entered value
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// define NumberButton widget
// its shape is round
class NumberButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  final double size;
  final Color color;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  //final Function onSubmit;

  const NumberButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
    required this.size,
    required this.color,
    required this.controller,
    //required this.onSubmit,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: color,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size / 2),
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          controller.text += number.toString();
          //print(number.toString());
          final dio = Dio();
          DateTime datetime = DateTime.now();
          final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          final String? token = prefs.getString('Token');
          final String? UUID = prefs.getString('udid');
          String dateStr =
              "${datetime.day}-${datetime.month}-${datetime.year} ${datetime.hour}:${datetime.minute}";
          await prefs.setString('DateTime', dateStr);
          await prefs.setString('PainScore', number.toString());
          //prefs.remove('PainValues');
          final String? encodedpainlist = prefs.getString('PainValues');

          if (encodedpainlist !=null )
            {
              final decodedList = json.decode(encodedpainlist!);
              decodedList.add({'time': dateStr, 'points': number.toString()});
              //decodedList.append({});
              var listlength = decodedList.length;
              print(listlength);
              String? encodedList = json.encode(decodedList);
              await prefs.setString('PainValues', encodedList);
              print("setting tempro value");
              await prefs.setString('tempro', "data persisted!");
              print("tempro value is set");
            }
          else { // This will execute only once when the app is initialised
            List list = [];
            list.add({'time': dateStr, 'points': number.toString()});
            print(list);
            String? encodedList = json.encode(list);
            await prefs.setString('PainValues', encodedList);
            print("Encoded List"+encodedList);
            String? tempro = await prefs.getString("tempro");
            print("below is from tempro");
            print(tempro);
          }


          dio.options.headers['origin'] = "whatever";
          try {
            final response = await dio.request(
              'https://example.co.uk/api/v1/score/',
              data: {
                "uuid": UUID,
                "painScore": number.toString(),
                "timeStamp": dateStr
              },
              options: Options(
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
                  'content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
              ),
            );
            print('Here is the Full data: ${response.data}');
            print('Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
            var _response = response.data;
            if (response.statusCode == 200 &&
                _response["painScoreSaved"] == true) {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                        content: Text(
                          "Pain Score Recorded:  ${number.toString()}",
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ));
            } else {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                        content: Text(
                          "Network Error, Try Again",
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ));
            }
          } on DioError catch (e) {
            print('here is the error $e');
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                      content: Text(
                        "Network Error, Try Again",
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                      ),
                    ));
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            number.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

chart.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ViewPainScores extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewPainScores({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ViewPainScores> createState() => _ViewPainScoresState();
}

class _ViewPainScoresState extends State<ViewPainScores> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadpainscore();
  }
  List users = [
    {"time": "Nil", "points": "No Pain Score Recorded Yet!"},
  ];
  loadpainscore() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? encodedpainlist = prefs.getString('PainValues');
    print(encodedpainlist);
    if(encodedpainlist!=null)
      {
        List decodedList = json.decode(encodedpainlist!);
        setState(() {
          users = decodedList.reversed.toList();
        });
      }
    else
      {
        print("all the values are null");
      }

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Map with List"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
                endIndent: 10,
                indent: 10,
              ),
              itemCount: users.length,

              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // parsing the maps in the list before passing them into the extracted widget
                // the itemBuilder iterates through the list
                final name = users[index]['time'];
                final status = users[index]['points'];
                return CustomListTile(name: name, status: status);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name, status;
  const CustomListTile({Key? key, required this.name, required this.status}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {

      },
      child: ListTile(
        /*leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 20,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/profileavatar.png")),*/
        title: Text("Pain Score:"+status),
        subtitle: Text("Recorded Date & Time: " +name),
     
      ),
    );
  }
}
```